# I don't understand the error I get while activating environment in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I reinstalled Miniconda (version 4.3.21) at c:\Miniconda3, created an environment named `data` and also installed some packages in this environment. The Python version came with this Conda is 3.6. However, before installing the Miniconda, version 3.4 of Python was already installed on my system (location c:\python34). OS is Windows 7 (32 bits).

On command line, I can run command like `conda info --envs` or `conda create -n data`. I can even open Python IDLE by running `idle` command which opens the IDLE for Python which came wih Miniconda. But when I try to run `activate data`, it shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ2Xn.jpg).

However, when I run command line as administrator, I am able to activate environment. If I remember correctly, earlier I was able run all commands without needing any admin privileges. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening is that your user likely has the original Python executable(or old Miniconda Python) in your users PATH and this is found before Minconda Python. When run as Admin(because installing to C:\Miniconda requires admin privileges) it finds the correct executable that is in the System PATH. Having both a standard Python and Miniconda in your user Path will cause issues as it will use the first Python.exe found based on your PATH.

Check Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.

Put Minconda before the standard Python or remove the standard python(there is no difference between standard python and the python included with Miniconda as they both come from python.org). You may also need to set the permissions on the entire C:\Miniconda directory for your user. Even though you have admin access you will still need to escalate privileges if you don't set permissions for your actual user.

Comment: @JohnMorrision I checked that and here is what I see:

User Variable - 
`PATH : C:\Miniconda3;C:\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Miniconda3\Scripts`

System Variable - 
`path : C:\Miniconda3;C:\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib;`

Do you see anything wrong here?

Comment: @mayankkaizen It looks like Miniconda is first so it should be found correctly. I think the issue is that your user does not have correct permissions to execute all files in the Miniconda directory. Even when you are an admin you still need to escalate privileges to access the files. Set the permissions to full access on the entire directory for you user. It is usually best to install Miniconda/Anaconda in your users home folder to bypass this extra configuration.